# Android: XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance says cannot find symbol class newInstance

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlpullparser

I'm trying to parse XML document using `XmlPullParser` but I've the following error

`Gradle: error: cannot find symbol class newInstance`

Creating `XmlPullParserFactory`

`XmlPullParserFactory ppf = new XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();`

How to configure `Gradle` to discover `XmlPullParser` properly?

Comment: `import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory` do you this import statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
XmlPullParserFactory ppf = new XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
```

should be

```
XmlPullParserFactory ppf = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
```

You must use `new` to invoke constructors, not static methods.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to remove the `new` keyword from your statement that's all.

Because `new` is basically used to create object via calling the constructor of the your class and in this case we are creating a new instance of `PullParserFactory` using `newInstance()` method and we are calling this method so we do not need to use this.

And The factory will always return instances of `KXmlParser` and `KXmlSerializer`.